# SQLDeveloper - How do I generate an ER diagram that shows all the interconnecting tables given two tables in the same database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have tables TableA and TableD within the same oracle database. I want to be able to automatically generate an ER diagram as such in SQLdeveloper (example below) to find the relations:

TableA <--> TableB <--> TableC <--> TableD

Tables TableB and TableC are just example tables that relate between TableA and TableD.

I'm currently digging through the database schema and trying to figure out if there is a relational link between these two tables via the foreign keys. It's tedious and I tried looking for a visualization tool to assist me.

I'm aware of how to generate ER diagrams by going to *File → Data Modeler → Import → Data Dictionary* but it doesn't seem to show the options to generate intermediate relations between two tables. I would have to select a bunch of tables manually. My colleague claims that there is a feature that does what I want but I can't find it.

If anyone could let me know, that would be appreciated. I'm currently running sqldeveloper version 4.1.3.20

Thanks

Comment: Please define what you mean by 'relate' or put another way, are there any foreign key constraints between these 4 tables? Also, your version (4.1) is ANCIENT.

Comment: That's the right approach.  The modeler (import) doesn't "generate" tables.  It merely builds a model based on the chosen tables from the dictionary.  There are other ways to find references.  Navigate to a table of interest.  In the constraints tab, you can find any foreign key constraints.  In the dependencies tab, you can find those tables (and other objects) which have references to this table.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Given TableA and TableD in the example as parameters, I am wondering if there is a feature that generates an ER diagram showing how tableA and tableD are related in the database schema (how they are joined or maybe disjoined). My inspection of the schema via the foreign key constraints and documents suggests it is disjoined but I'd like to double-check with what I described if it exists. Also, my workplace loves their outdated software and getting new software approved for the network is a pain.

Comment: Why not just ask your colleague to show you the feature?

Comment: @Belayer Yeah, he didn't remember, hence why I'm asking on SO. Anyways, I don't think this feature exists so I'll close this question